# Greater Than and Less than support for ENUM mapping in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, enums, hql, hibernate-criteria

If i am using default mapping ( ordinal mapping ) for ENUM in hibernate than can i use Greater Than and Less Than operators in HQL and Criteria Query and get Expected results.

For eg. 
I have ENUM Month with values JAN,FEB,MAR ...

then greater than FEB should match MAR, APR ...

Comment: Yes you can. But you pass month order number. For example for february 1(if start index is 0). But you can not pass enum like FEB,MAR and etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Afsun. If i change mapping type from Ordinal to Enum name  
then would it still work if i pass integer as argument . 
If not then is there any support for that built into hibernate ?

Comment: No. Hibernate has not future like that. Same problem also occurred for me.